# Elastcisearch copy two fields to the object for every document

Tags: elasticsearch

How to copy two fields in the the object for the same document.
I have an object in the elasticsearch

```
    {
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "AXWTrVr6LIkj1JVvPnDX",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "field1": 1,
          "field2": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to copy `field1` and `field2` into the test_object for every document.
Expected result

```
        {
      "took": 0,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "AXWTrVr6LIkj1JVvPnDX",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "field1": 1,
              "field2": 2,
              "test_object":{
                 "field1": 1,
                 "field2": 2
}
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I am trying to do it via next script, but I don't understand what is wrong

```
POST test_index/doc/update
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "field1":1
    }
  },
  "script" : {
      "inline": "ctx._source.test_field.field1 = ctx._source.field1 ctx._source.test_field.field2 = ctx._source.field2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to hit the [`_update_by_query` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

Then, since `test_field` doesn't exist in your document, you need to create it:

This should work for you:

```
POST test_index/_update_byquery
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "field1":1
    }
  },
  "script" : {
      "inline": "ctx._source.test_field = ['field1': ctx._source.field1, 'field2': ctx._source.field2]"
  }
}
```